# How to disable splashColor only for TextField in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to disable ripple effect on a `TextField`.

`splashColor: Colors.transparent` removes ripple effect on others widgets as well.

I want to remove ripple effect only on `TextField`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way, you only need to add `Theme` to your `TextField`

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(splashColor: Colors.transparent),
  child: TextField(),
),
```